# Executing program from remote computer

Tags: powershell, service, remote-desktop

I have a program on a remote computer which needs a user to be logged on to execute the refresh for updating the data. Right now we keep the remote session active and press the `REFRESH` button everyday to update the data but we want to automate the process.

We want to create a script which makes the program think that the desktop is interactive and that the user is logged in and we would also like to refresh the data every 24 hours. We also wrote a script to keep the service running if in case it shuts down which is as below: The example here is `Fax`

```
$ServiceName = 'Fax'
$arrService = Get-Service -Name $ServiceName

if ($arrService.Status -ne 'Running') {
    $ServiceStarted = $false
}
Else {
    $ServiceStarted = $true
}

while ($ServiceStarted -ne $true) {
    Start-Service $ServiceName
    write-host $arrService.status
    write-host 'Service started'
    Start-Sleep -seconds 60

    if ($arrService.Status -eq 'Running') {
        $ServiceStarted = $true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered just running something like https://autohotkey.com/ on the remote computer?

Comment: Would a scheduled task with GUI automation not work in this case?  You could probably get away with something like that.